# Vertically Align Images in Grid (CSS)

Tags: php, css

I've been messing about with this for a while now and my client is insisting that setting the image's position manually via CSS is not an acceptable solution. Basically I'm trying to vertically center the images in the parent DIV (which has a static height).

I was thinking about calculating the image size via PHP and then setting CSS rules for each image but imagine this is over complicating it.

May someone please take a look at the [demo here](http://uptownlofts.ibistrail.com/our-community/preferred-employers/) and advise of a potential solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to calculate things here, CSS has solution for everything, the trick is to use `display: table-cell;` with `vertical-align: middle;`

CSS

```
div {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BdLHR/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a case for the `<table>` element. It's arguably tabular data.

When you do that, you can give the table cells a `vertical-align`:

```
table td { vertical-align: middle; }
```

Comment: Well I've not seen the demo there :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using table styles, you can do this:

```
div {
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
}
div img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x5j43o08/11/